# I'm acquiring a VARCHAR variable through php, and want to show it using HTML/CSS. How do I auto format it so that it isn't one long sentence

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, varchar

I basically want to automatically add line breaks to a VARCHAR variable I acquire from a mysql database trough PHP, so that it shows right. At the moment when I show it trough HTML, all it does is give me a long sentence.

I imagine this can be done with CSS, but `overflow: scroll` just makes it scroll to the right and left. Use of javascript or JQuery is also accepted.

Comment: is it one long continuous string without spaces? where do you want to add line breaks? anywhere? after every x characters? after every fulls stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it really is a long string with no spaces or line breaks then the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) CSS property can be set to `break-word`.  There are [some examples on the MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap).  But, like others have said, if this is a normal sentence with spaces in it then a browser will wrap it automatically providing it's not in a `pre` block.  If its plain text with line breaks that you want preserved then you can either convert the `\n` to `<br>` like elusive suggested, or just place it in a `pre` block to preserve its text formatting.

Comment: Thank you! word-wrap was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

by any chance are the spaces in this long string `&nbsp;` eg. non breaking spaces? If so then just replace them with normal spaces.

if not then please show us some of this html that is generated and the code that generates it.

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP's `nl2br`-function is what you are looking for. It converts any linebreaks (`\n`) into html-breaks (`<br />`). Alternatively, you could take a look at the `white-space` CSS command.